# E possível criar cron jobs de envio de emails com tempo variavel?

Tags: laravel, envio-de-email, cron

Gostaria de saber se e possível criar um cron job para enviar emails, com um timestamp variável dependendo de uma informação inserida no banco de dados.

Exemplo:

Preencho um formulário informando o email a mensagem e a data/hora que deve ser enviado;
Esse formulário preenchido com essas informações vai para o banco de dados;
Quando essa data/hora chegar ele executar esse cron job "variável" e dispara o email;

E possível fazer isso usando com o laravel se não qual seria a melhor solução pra aplicar isso?

Comment: Olá, o cronjob vai rodar no tempo que você predefinir no arquivo `Kernel.php`. Você até pode rodar ele a cada 1 minuto e sempre buscar os registros que foram programados para rodar neste minuto. Por exemplo, quando gravar a entrada no banco com o envio para hoje às 18:05, quando o cronjob rodar nesta hora, filtre estas entradas e faça o envio delas.

Comment: Outro modo e talvez mais prático, é utilizar as Queues. Talvez algo assim: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58724537/6394559

Answer (score -3):

Apliquei uma solução com base no comentário deste tópico. Minha solucao foi a seguinte.

Criei um cron job no sistema operacional que executa o schedule do laravel a cada minuto. Para configurar um cron job no sistema pode utilizar os seguintes comandos:

Para linux:

```
nano crontab -e
```

Para Mac:

```
EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano crontab -u nomedoseuusuario -e
```

Para executar os comandos e recomendado ter acesso como root;

Após abrir o arquivo adicione um intervalo de tempo para que o comando seja executado configurando o ***** segue abaixo um link de um site para gerar intervalos de tempo para cronjob.

https://crontab.guru/

Segue o comando que utilizei dentro do cronjob

```
* * * * * cd /Users/nomedousuario/caminhodoseuprojetolaravel && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

No meu schedule apenas criei um command para comparar a data e hora atual da linha inserida no banco de dados se a verificação for verdadeira ele dispara o email.